# Getting Parse Error Unexpected "

Tags: php

I am getting an error with the following message :-
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\game.php on line 12`

Here is the source code :-

```
<?php
 $words=$_GET['words'];
  $array=explode(",",$words);
    $j=count($array)-1;
 goto a;

a:  shuffle($array);
    $num=$array[0];
    echo "The Number Is = $num";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Please Enter The Number Within 10 Seconds";
    echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']\" ";  **<--Line 12**
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\"";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Press Me! \"";
    $input=$_GET['num'];
    goto b;

b: if($input==$array[0] && $array!=NULL)
    {
        array_pop($array);
        goto a;
        }
    elseif($array!=NULL)
        {
            goto a;
    }
else
    break;
?>
```

Please don't say about the GOTO but rather on how to fix the error as I am only experimenting with it to see if it would solve the given question.

Comment: Had to post this: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @AmalMurali - Already saw that in the PHP manual, so any way to resolve the above query?

Comment: You don't escape single quotes in double quotes.
    `printf ("<form method=\"get\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\" ");`

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which one is line 12?

Comment: @PranavJituri: You need to use concatenation here. Or lose the single-quotes: `printf ("<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\"");` — You don't need to quote the key name when it's inside double-quotes.

Comment: @Gil - I hope you are satisfied now.
Fred-ii- Already tried that but not working still

Comment: @AmalMurali - It worked mate. Write that as an answer and I ll accept it. Also, just executed and guess what, an infinite loop :P

Is there any function in PHP so that the execution can wait till the input is not given again?

Comment: @AmalMurali - Fair Enough. I was just experimenting with goto and yea the result was catastrophic. Actually, here is one question of mine on which currently I am working but no answers, only some random comments. Think you could help me on this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463148/passing-values-to-and-fro-from-client-to-server-repeatedly-in-php

Comment: @PranavJituri Check my answer for a much less confusing way to write this.

Comment: @Gil - I wish I could select more than one answers. Yours also worked, but could you please elaborate a bit more on how it is working using the `.` operator?

Comment: @PranavJituri: RTM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @AmalMurali - Fair Enough. Could you also please check the above question which I said in the above comments?

Comment: @PranavJituri: I don't mean to be rude, but you really have to get a hold of the basic syntax before starting to code :) By the way, checked that question, but couldn't really understand what you were asking. Good luck though!

Comment: @AmalMurali - Sure thing. Will read the manual. The question is that I want Dynamic Input/Output After the PHP script has been executed to execute it on same page with different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']\" ";
```

Into

```
echo '<form method="get" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';
```

It's much more simpler for the eyes.

Comment: Actually, just use Smarty!

Answer (score 4):

I'll comment on all of it.

First, to fix your syntax error (and the later HTML errors you'll have).  The single-quotes in the PHP_SELF substitution don't need escaped, you need to complete your opening tags, and you need to close your form tag.

```
<?php
 $words=$_GET['words'];
  $array=explode(",",$words);
    $j=count($array)-1;
 goto a;

a:  shuffle($array);
    $num=$array[0];
    echo "The Number Is = $num";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Please Enter The Number Within 10 Seconds";
    echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']\" >";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Press Me! \" />";
    echo "</form>";
    $input=$_GET['num'];
    goto b;

b: if($input==$array[0] && $array!=NULL)
    {
        array_pop($array);
        goto a;
        }
    elseif($array!=NULL)
        {
            goto a;
    }
else
    break;
```

Now, to make it not spaghetti code and to simplify your logic:

```
<?php
$words=$_GET['words'];
$array=explode(",",$words);

while (sizeOf($array) > 0) {
    shuffle($array);
    $num = $array[0];
    echo "The Number Is = $num";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Please Enter The Number Within 10 Seconds";
    echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']\" >";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Press Me! \" />";
    echo "</form>";
    $input = $_GET['num'];
    if($input === $array[0]) {
        array_pop($array);
    }
}
```

Now it's at least clear what the code does - that is, the form is provided with a comma-delimited list of numbers on the query parameter "words".  The list is shuffled, and the user is asked to enter the new "first" item - effectively a random item from the list.  When submitted by the user, "num" is passed.  If this number is the same as the first in the list, it removes the *last* number.  Either way, as long as the array is non-null, then loops back on itself (effectively *ad infinitum*, spitting out the same form for each number on the list.  I'm not sure this is what you wanted, since you're not handling $_GET[num] as an array.

Assuming you actually get a form, rather than just peg your server, the script then checks if "num" is present and, if so, removes it from the numbers list.

This is where it gets interesting; on submission, the script is started again.  "words" is empty, so the form asks the user to enter "".  If it wasn't, the list would have been re-randomized, so even if the user dutifully entered what was asked, the script wouldn't recognize it.

This is one of the reasons we don't use GOTO; it obfuscates your code flow.  What's clear in a while loop is inscrutable using GOTO.

---

So what I assume is *supposed* to be the requirement:

You're presented with a number to enter.  You enter it and submit the form.  The number is removed from the list, and you're asked to enter another one.  Once it's empty, it would be nice if you're told that.

So, to do this in a way that makes sense, let's do this using some OOP.

I know what you're going to say: this appears to be *more* complex - however, I want you to note that what baking everything into a class does: it encapsulates the stuff you're doing into one place, and separates out each phase of the request into separate functions.

Additionally, comments notwithstanding, it effectively documents nonobvious and repetitive tasks, like getting items off the $_REQUEST (or $_GET) object, or getting an item from an array (if it's an array and if the item exists on it) in a way that is safe and predictable.

Lastly, it's *readable*.  It's a bit of work to look at the contents of the while loop and work out what it does; in this class, you can tell: it checks that the array is not empty and that the submitted number is the same as the requested number; if so, it removes that number.

Additionally, rather than shuffle the list each time, we just pick each one off at random.

```
<?php
class RandomNumberGame {
    private $startCount;
    private $numberMax;
    private $numbers;
    private $index;
    /**
        Produce an array containing $count random numbers between 0 and $max
    */
    public function generateRandoms($count, $max) {
        $nums = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 1) {
            $nums[] = rand(0, $max);
        }
        return $nums;
    }
    /**
        Get an item from an array if it exists; if not, or if the array doesn't exist, return null
    */
    public function getIfExists($array, $item) {
        if (empty($array)) return null;
        if (!array_key_exists($item, $array)) return null;
        return $array[$item];
    }
    /**
        returns a random number from the list of numbers
    */
    function pickRandomNumber() {
        return rand(0, sizeof($this->numbers) - 1);
    }
    /**
        Handle the request data
            $request
                ['nums'] - list of numbers with which to populate $this->numbers
                ['index'] - the index of the currently-selected number
                ['num'] - the user's entry
        If nums[index] == num, that item is removed and a new index is selected.
    */
    public function processRequest($request) {
        $nums = $this->getIfExists($request, 'nums');
        if (empty($nums)) {
            $this->numbers = $this->generateRandoms($this->startCount, $this->numberMax);
        } else {
            $this->numbers = explode(',', $nums);
        }

        $this->index = $this->getIfExists($request, 'index');
        if (empty($this->index)) {
            $this->index = $this->pickRandomNumber();
        }

        $num = $this->getIfExists($request, 'num');
        if (empty($num)) return;
        while (!empty($this->numbers) && $this->getCurrentNumber() === $num) {
            $this->removeCurrentNumber();
        }
    }
    /**
        Removes the entry in $this->numbers pointed to by $this->index, and assigns $this->index a new random position
    */
    public function removeCurrentNumber() {
        // In $nums, replace 1 items at $index with [] - effectively, remove item $index from $num
        array_splice($this->numbers, $this->index, 1, array());
        // Pick a new random item
        $this->index = $this->pickRandomNumber();
    }
    /**
        Get the currently selected number
    */
    public function getCurrentNumber() {
        return $this->getIfExists($this->numbers, $this->index);
    }
    /**
        Generate the form for output to the user
        If there are no numbers left, provide a congratulation, and a link to start over
    */
    public function getForm($endpoint) {
        if (sizeof($this->numbers) === 0) {
            return "Hey, you're done! <a href=\"{$endpoint}\">Start over</a>.";
        }
        $nums = join(',', $this->numbers);
        return <<<HEREDOC
            <form method="post" action="{$endpoint}">
                <input type="hidden" name="nums" value="{$nums}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="index" value="{$this->index}" />
                <label for="num">
                    The number is {$this->getCurrentNumber()}<br />
                    Please enter the number within 10 seconds<br />
                    <input id="num" type="text" name="num" autofocus/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Press Me!" />
            </form>
            <!-- Optional: define some Javascript to disable the form in 10 seconds -->
HEREDOC;
    }
    public function RandomNumberGame($startCount = 10, $numberMax = 100) {
        //Basic initialization
        $this->startCount = $startCount;
        $this->numberMax = $numberMax;
    }
}
//Finally, the program:
$rng = new RandomNumberGame();
$rng->processRequest($_REQUEST);
echo $rng->getForm($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing `>` in three lines

```
echo "Please Enter The Number Within 10 Seconds";
echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">"; 
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Press Me! \">";
```

Yours:

```
echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']\" "; 
                                                          ^-- here
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\"";
                                       ^-- here
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Press Me! \"";
                                                 ^-- here
```

*Plus,* `[\'PHP_SELF\']` You should not be escaping single quotes.

Use `[PHP_SELF]` or `{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}` wrapping the variable in curly braces.

Comment: This will still produce a syntax error. You do *not* need to quote the keys inside double-quotes ;)

Comment: I removed the escape quotes for `['PHP_SELF']` @AmalMurali I had noticed it earlier, simply forgot to integrate it in my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: [It's still the same](https://eval.in/122136). You don't need the single-quotes, at all :)

Comment: Should that be `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` then? @AmalMurali or `{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}`

Comment: Both are correct, @Fred. See [this demo](https://eval.in/122139). Se the manual, too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-80

Comment: Thanks Amal. OP still had missing `>` in 3 lines, so that would have caused a problem as well. I think I've gone the "extra mile" as it were. @AmalMurali Plus, I was the first to spot it hahaha! No big deal, OP has his/her solution, it's all that counts.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yeah, I did see that. I was just merely pointing out the mistake in your answer. Not sure if I like OP's way of writing HTML though. Hardly readable. Anyway, here's a +1 from me for *also* fixing the markup :)

Comment: Thanks Amal :) That's why (as you said) it was hard to find "all" of the mistakes because of the way the code was written. @AmalMurali It took me a while at first, but spotted them "all" ;-)

Comment: "Remove single quotes altogether" is not good advice, IMO. It could mess up if there are other defined constants in your code. I'd recommend using **1.** [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax, **2.** `printf()` with placeholders — [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19816805/1438393). **3.** Concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap server variable with brackets:

```
echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf ("<form method=\"get\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\" ");
```

Two errors. You can't escape single quotes in a double quoted string, and when you are working with an array inside a string, you need to surround it with {}.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you're putting in single quotes for the array of $_SERVER:

`echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']\" ";`

simply use

`echo "<form method=\"get\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\" ";`

instead. the idea of the '' inside the array is to pass the string. no need to pass it within a quotes.

Comment: `"<form method=\"get\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\" `
is another way of doing it aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt it need a space before the != and after 
From

```
b: if($input==$array[0] && $array!=NULL)
```

to this

```
b: if(($input==$array[0]) && ($array != NULL))
```

Have wrapped it in extra brackets for good measure too

Comment: This should be a suggested edit to my code rather than an answer to my problem. Could you please read again the question and see if you can answer it?

Comment: The order of the conditions doesn't necessarily make sense, either. If `$array` is null then the second guard condition isn't going to stop the first one from throwing an 'Undefined index' error

Comment: Sorry Prav i didnt totally understand your question now I read it back.